# Hyper-V client regularly disconnects network adapter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

We recently installed a Windows Server 2012 R2 guest on one of our Server 2008 R2 based Hyper-V hosts.

This machine was going offline every night around midnight. Upon checking the event log, I noticed the Hyper-V-Netsvc on the client logging that the network adapter was disconnected. Shortly after, it logs that the adapter was connected again. This pattern seems to repeat on all workdays (not on the weekend).

My search lead me to the following knowledge base articles:

- [The network connection of a running Hyper-V virtual machine is lost under heavy outgoing network traffic on a Windows Server 2008 R2-based computer (KB974909)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974909)
- [Network connection is lost on a Windows Server 2003-based Hyper-V VM (KB981836)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981836)

But neither seem to fit our situation. The client isn't 2003 and I don't have to restart the client to fix the problem, it fixes itself.

Because I wasn't sure that the machine and the applications on it were installed correctly, I've re-installed the operating system last week and didn't install any of the applications on it yet. The same problem happened tonight again.

Comment: Have you tried moving the VM to another host to see if the problem occurs there?

Comment: @joeqwerty I haven't tried that yet. We only have one other Hyper-V host in the network and its hardware configuration is identical to the other host. Also, all other guests (all 2008 R2) on both hosts run fine. But I'll give it a try anyways, can't hurt.

Comment: @joeqwerty I've moved the VM to the other host and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you tried the hotfix KB974909 that you mentioned? It looks close enough to your issue to apply and try.

Comment: @ByronC. I have installed neither as we only have the issue with the 2012R2 VM and I wasn't aware of any heavy traffic on a freshly installed server with no applications.

Comment: @ByronC. MS support instructed me to install KB974909. The installer said it isn't applicable to my system. Apparently a build mismatch. Still working on the issue with them.